# How to convert a navigation list with depth levels to a parent-child flat list?

Tags: python, data-structures

I have these lists in python:

```
doc_id = ['10','20','21','22','30','31','32','40','41','42','421','422']

text = ['1. Chapter', '2. Chapter', '2.1 Chapter', 
        '2.2 Chapter','3. Chapter', '3.1 Chapter','3.2 Chapter',
        '4. Chapter','4.1. Chapter','4.2 Chapter', 
        '4.2.1 Chapter','4.2.2 Chapter']

depth= [1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3]
```

where **doc_id** is the id of each navigation item, **text** is the label of each item and **depth** is the item's depth. All the lists match their index. They could be grouped in one list of lists like [doc_id, text, depth] but I decided to separate them to build an easier approach.

What I want is to create a parent-child list like this (0 is root of course)

child , text          parent

```
['10', '1.   Chapter', 0  ]
['20', '2.   Chapter', 0  ]
['21', '2.1. Chapter', 20 ]  
['22', '2.2. Chapter', 20 ]
['30', '3    Chapter', 0  ]
['31', '3.1. Chapter', 30 ]
['32', '3.2. Chapter', 32 ]
['40', '4.   Chapter', 0  ]
['41', '4.1. Chapter', 40 ]
['42', '4.2. Chapter', 40 ]
['421','4.2.1. Chapter', 42 ]
['422','4.2.2. Chapter', 42 ]
```

This is what I've been trying. I'm looping through all items and checking if the next depth is higher or equal than the counter of the current depth and then reducing the counter to zero, but can't come up with the full solution.

Could you please give me a hand, maybe a hint.

```
docs_id = ['10','20','21','22','30','31','32','40','41','42','421','422']

text = ['1. Chapter', '2. Chapter', '2.1 Chapter',
        '2.2 Chapter','3. Chapter', '3.1 Chapter','3.2 Chapter',
        '4. Chapter','4.1. Chapter','4.2 Chapter',
        '4.2.1 Chapter','4.2.2 Chapter']

depth= [1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3]

currentdepth = 0

tree = []

current_doc_id = 0

for i, value in enumerate(text):

    newdepth = depth[i]
    doc_id = docs_id[i]
    title = text[i]

    if newdepth > currentdepth:
        tree.append((doc_id, title, current_doc_id))
        currentdepth += 1
    elif newdepth == currentdepth:
        tree.append((doc_id, title, current_doc_id))
    else:
        while newdepth>currentdepth:
            currentdepth -=1

    current_doc_id = doc_id

for i in tree:
    print(i)
```

Comment: title = value  ,,,,

Comment: whats the rule of third variable in []

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
docs_id = ['10','20','21','22','30','31','32','40','41','42','421','422']

text = ['1. Chapter', '2. Chapter', '2.1 Chapter',
        '2.2 Chapter','3. Chapter', '3.1 Chapter','3.2 Chapter',
        '4. Chapter','4.1. Chapter','4.2 Chapter',
        '4.2.1 Chapter','4.2.2 Chapter']

depth= [1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3]

currentdepth = 1

tree = []

current_doc_id = 0

for i, value in enumerate(text):

    newdepth = depth[i]
    doc_id = docs_id[i]
    title = value


    if newdepth > currentdepth:

        global current_doc_id
        current_doc_id =  docs_id[i-1]
        tree.append([doc_id, title, int(current_doc_id)])

        currentdepth += 1
    elif newdepth == currentdepth:
        tree.append([doc_id, title, int(current_doc_id)])
    else:
        current_doc_id=0
        tree.append([doc_id, title, int(current_doc_id)])
        while newdepth>currentdepth:
            currentdepth -=1
        currentdepth-=1





for i in tree:
    print(i)
```

Comment: would you know how to get the depth of a particular item, say if I want to know the depth of the Chapter 4 I should get the number 4, but Chapter 4.2 I should get only 2?

Answer (score 0):

Pandas version:

```
import pandas as pd

doc_id = ['10','20','21','22','30','31','32','40','41','42','421','422']
text = ['1. Chapter', '2. Chapter', '2.1 Chapter', 
        '2.2 Chapter','3. Chapter', '3.1 Chapter','3.2 Chapter',
        '4. Chapter','4.1. Chapter', '4.2 Chapter', 
        '4.2.1 Chapter','4.2.2 Chapter']
depth = [1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3]


df = pd.DataFrame({"doc_id" : doc_id, "text" : text, "depth" : depth})

d = {0: 0}
def get_parent(row):    
    d[row["depth"]] = row["doc_id"]
    return d.get(row["depth"]-1)

df["depth"] = df.apply(get_parent, axis=1)

print(df.values.tolist())

# Output:
# [['10', '1. Chapter', 0],
#  ['20', '2. Chapter', 0],
#  ['21', '2.1 Chapter', '20'],
#  ['22', '2.2 Chapter', '20'],
#  ['30', '3. Chapter', 0],
#  ['31', '3.1 Chapter', '30'],
#  ['32', '3.2 Chapter', '30'],
#  ['40', '4. Chapter', 0],
#  ['41', '4.1. Chapter', '40'],
#  ['42', '4.2 Chapter', '40'],
#  ['421', '4.2.1 Chapter', '42'],
#  ['422', '4.2.2 Chapter', '42']]
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I love this approach with Pandas, I had no idea Pandas could do this. Thank you. However I'm using Python 3.4 and I have problems using this library. But I will keep it in my personal cookbook.